# USB Current limiting function

Tags: usb, short-circuit, current-limiting, decoupling-capacitor

I have a little question. This is a USB current limiting function in Orange Pi Schematic. I have tried research it but wonder how does this circuit work since Vcc - Decoupling Capacitor - GND. It's weird. There is nothing that tells me that this circuit will prevent short-circuit(limit current) when VCC connects GND. I wonder what is the real function of this circuit.

[image]

Comment: I checked the schematic if there's a limiting function through the PMIC, but there's none. The DC input (5V) is fed directly to the [PMIC](https://linux-sunxi.org/images/b/bc/AXP805_Datasheet_V1.0_en.pdf), USB, and some other converters without any current limiting. The buck converters and LDOs inside the PMIC have current limiting internally, but this does not apply to the USB.

Comment: @RohatKılıç thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no current limiting. The incoming 5V supply is directly connected to many places such as this USB connector without proper current limiting.

Answer (score -1):

From the first look, it weird.
Suppose, the net 5V is "minus 5 Volts". And this power is current limited and self-protected  (it is not the main power line of computer)
Probably DP and DM are connected via caps to Host controller.